# Long wait until POST

Tags: boot, post, delay

Here are the specs to put things into context:

- ECS P4VXASD2+ (V5.0) motherboard
- Intel Pentium 4 Northwood 2.8 GHz (512 KB L2, 533 MHz FSB)
- 2x 512 MB PC2100 DDR266 RAM
- 128 MB NVIDIA GeForce FX 5200 AGP
- WD Caviar SE 80 GB IDE HDD
- Gigabyte CD-RW drive
- OKIA 300W ATX PSU

So, everytime I try to boot up this computer, it takes at least 10-15 seconds before it will POST. All my other machines will post within 1-2 seconds, but this one takes a particularly long time.

I've read suggestions from a Google search to swap the CMOS battery, check BIOS settings, and double check CMOS jumper. Still after follow those, it takes a while to POST.

What else could be causing a long delay before POSTing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does a long pause happen at a certain stage in the POST? And which one.

Things to try:

1. Turn off all connected equipment and take out as many cards as you can.
   If POST time returns to normal, reconnect them one by one (including RAM).
2. If you're using a USB keyboard, try PS2 if you can
3. Disable legacy USB support
4. Check for updates to the Intel chipset driver
5. Check hard-disk jumpers and try different settings for master/slave/cable-select
6. Check for BIOS update (but take extreme care with flashing)
7. Ask a qualified repairman for help, or if this is a new machine use the warranty

Comment: Especially check #2 and #3 of harrymc's list.  My own PC takes a while to post when my USB printer is turned on during boot.  The printer has a built in card reader as well.  I also experience some delay from my external hard drive, which is connected via USB as well.  When neither of those are plugged in/turned on, my PC posts immediately.

Comment: My machine does not use any USB equipment, seeing as it won't be recognized immediately. (There is no OS currently installed.)

I have a PCI modem and I will try to run the machine without it.

Comment: #5 was my problem, but with the CD-ROM & DVD-ROM drives not being set to master & slave.